# Locate the user's location in a map with multiple pins

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation, user-location

I need to see user location using a custom annotation, and then I add more annotaions of various types in the vicinity of the user (eg monuments, restaurants cinema ...). If I write the code in this method displays the user's location.

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *) manager
 didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *) newLocation
        fromLocation:(CLLocation *) oldLocation {

    //......

   MyAnnotation *annotationUser = [[MyAnnotation alloc]initWithCoordinates:self.coordinate  title:@"YOU ARE HERE" subTitle:@"via Giorgio Giulini 2"];

   [self.mapView addAnnotation:self.annotationUser];


}
```

If I add the method

```
 - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapview viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
 {
      //.....
  }
```

to create the other annotations, the user's location is no longer displayed. Why?

Comment: You're adding a new annotation every time the location manger gets anew user location? That doesn't seem right. If you're happy with just the blue dot for the user you can drop the `annotationUser` stuff and just set `mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
    - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapview viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
 {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotation class]]) {

        return nil;

    } else {

        //.....

    }


  }
```